# Relacion de dos tablas tipo ENUM

Tags: mysql

Estoy diseñando una base de datos y me he topado con lo siguiente:

Quiero relacionar dos tablas usando mysql usando llave foranea y si es posible el tipo de dato ENUM

He estado buscando en Internet pero no sale nada relacionado a relacionar dos tablas usando ENUM y foreign key

Comment: La descripción de tus tablas, ¿cuáles son las columnas que deseas usar para relacionar dichas tablas? ayudaría mucho para comprender mejor como ayudarte